# Replacing internal functions with testdouble.js?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testdoublejs

Is it possible to `td.replace` an internal function in a node.js module when testing with [testdouble.js](https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js)?

The internal function consists of a DB call, so I do not want to test it.  I do however want to test that this function received the expected parameters.

For example, given a node.js module:

```
module.exports = { record: recordEvent }

recordEvent = (event) =>
    var dbModel = map(event);
    persist(dbModel);

var map = (event) => 
    // some code that transforms event to the db specific representation (testable)

var persist = (model) =>
    // some SQL insert/update code here (not testable)
```

And the following test, that checks if persist gets the correct params:

```
recorder = require('event_recorder')
describe 'Event recorder module', ->
    it 'converts the event to a db model', ->

        var event = {...// mock event };
        var model = {...// mock model of the event };

        var persist = td.replace(recorder, 'persist')
        td.when(persist(model)).thenReturn(true)

        result = recorder.record(event)
        expected = true;

        result.should.be.equal(expected)
```

However the test throws an error:

> td.replace - No "persist" property was found

I understand why it has this error, its because the persist method is not public.  How else can I achieve this in testdouble?

Answer (score 1):

One option, as you insinuated, is to make the `persist` method public. Another option would be for `persist` to accept or make use of another function to perform the SQL query, and stub *that* function instead:

```
var executeQuery = td.function()

recorder.recordEvent(event, executeQuery)

td.verify(executeQuery('UPDATE ...'))
```